# Unlink (Symlink) Directory to Mounted Hard Disk

Tags: linux, symlink, ls, unlink, rm

I'm trying to remove a symlink that was created using:

```
ln -s /media/hdd2 /home/DocumentsLibrary/
```

These are the suggestions I've found & tried:

`rm /home/DocumentsLibrary`    (tried with and without the trailing slash)
but every time I get:

```
rm cannot remove '/home/DocumentsLibrary': Is a Directory
```

`unlink /home/DocumentsLibrary`    (tried with and without the trailing slash)
but every time I get:

```
unlink cannot remove '/home/DocumentsLibrary': Is a Directory
```

I am logged in as a user with `sudo -i` and I can do everything else as expected.

I've tried with the owner as root:root, and user:root (where user is my user name) and tried changing the permissions to 777 but nothing seems to work.

Having Googled this and visited many sites

including:

- https://superuser.com/questions/9181/how-to-remove-a-symbolic-link-to-a-directory
- https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/remove-symbolic-link/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/398818/how-to-remove-symbolic-link

The wisdom seems to be that either/both the rm / unlink statements above ***should*** work, but they don't in this case.

using `ls -ls` gives this:

```
4 drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Aug 6 11:35 DocumentsLibrary
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The given error message and the `ls` result suggests that `DocumentsLibrary` a real directory to me. Sym link should look like `DocumentsLibrary -> /media/hdd2`

Comment: Can you please try touching a file in `DocumentsLibrary` and then go to `media/hdd2` to see if the touched file is in it?

Comment: `rm /home/DocumentsLibrary/hdd2`. `DocumentsLibrary` is a directory, not a link. Your link was probably created inside that directory.

Comment: I've deleted my answer to spear OP of the harm of shooting themselves in the foot. `ls -s` command doesn't show the symlinks within a directory. Refer to LS(1).

Answer (score 1):

> using ls -ls gives this:
>
> ```
> 4 drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Aug 6 11:35 DocumentsLibrary
> ```

It seems that `DocumentsLibrary` already existed as directory when you tried to create symlink with this name. `ln -s` deals with trailing slash on destination in such cases differently:

```
ln -s /media/hdd2 /home/DocumentsLibrary/ (1)
ln -s /media/hdd2 /home/DocumentsLibrary  (2)
```

Case (1) will try to create symlink in `/home/DocumentsLibrary/` named after basename of original file, so `/home/DocumentsLibrary/hdd2` is created

Case (2) will try to create symlink in `/home/` with name `DocumentsLibrary` and should fail due to name conflict.

Hence, try to do the following:

```
ls -l /home/DocumentsLibrary/hdd2    # check that it is symlink
rm /home/DocumentsLibrary/hdd2
rmdir /home/DocumentsLibrary
ln -s /media/hdd2 /home/DocumentsLibrary
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to several replies above I figured out what happened, since I wasn't the one that created the symlink so didn't know if the /DocumentsLibrary existed as a directory at the time the link was created (it appears it must have been).

As suggested above, using touch to see if a file created in /DocumentsLibrary appeared in /media/hdd2 (it didn't) confirmed the symlinks were actually created **inside** the DocumentsLibrary directory to **each** of the directories on hdd2 rather than from /home/DocumentsLibrary to /media/hdd2. Not sure why I didn't sport that earlier.

Deleting each of the directories (within DoscumentsLibrary) using rm * then allowed the DocumentsLibrary itself to be deleted.

Thank you all.